# bs4 find sub-text / find_next

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

On the page [link](https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/species-risk-public-registry/cosewic-assessments-status-reports/edwards-beach-moth-2009.html), there is a section called "COSEWIC Assessment report". This section had emboldened text that heads categories and then non-bold text containing the information regarding that category. I am looking to scrape the non-bold text using bs4.

The HTML format for the bold text is wrapped in `<strong> sample text </strong>` tags in this way I can find the bold titles for each category using `result = s.find("strong", text=re.compile("Scientific name"))`.

That said, I would then like to scrape the information under that header for each given header. If I inspect the HTML for that section it looks like this.

```
<p>
<strong> Scientific name </strong>

<br>

"Anarta edwarsii"

</p>
```

So, from a starting point of having located the "scientific name" part, how do I get the "Anarta edwarsii" part.

I thought maybe bs4 find_next_sibling() would work or something of the sort but so far nothing has been successful. Also important to note is that I cannot use the text to look up the element because I have to repeat the processes for many different species. Therefore the header remains constant but its sub text will change.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `next_siblings` as resultset, iterate with list comprehension ans `join()` the results:

```
' '.join([x.text for x in soup.select_one('p:-soup-contains("Scientific name:") strong').next_siblings]).strip()
```

Output:

```
'"Anarta edwarsii"'
```

##### Alternativ example:

Select the `<p>` that contains the string "Scientific Name" get its `stripped_strings` as list `['Scientific name:', 'Anarta edwardsii']` and pick the second element:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'https://www.google.com/'
}

r = requests.get('https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/species-risk-public-registry/cosewic-assessments-status-reports/edwards-beach-moth-2009.html',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
list(soup.select_one('p:-soup-contains("Scientific name:")').stripped_strings)[-1]
```

Output:

```
'"Anarta edwarsii"'
```

Comment: hmm not too sure I follow. so the above finds the "p strong" tag and the next sibling and returns them together without their tags? I guess in that case my question is what goes in the brackets at the start?

Comment: `next_siblings` will give you a generator containing `[<br/>, 'Anarta edwardsii']` you can also pick the second elements, the `''.join()` will create a single string from list comprehension.

Comment: So yes I used the alternative example and it works very well for the scientific name. Thank you. However the next terms, for example, "Status" seem to be identical in the way that they are scripted in the HTML yet the same line will not produce the same result for the term "Status" This is because "Status" comes up earlier in the document. I need to append a way of only looking within the section of the HTML entitled "COSEWIC Assessment Summary". Can create a subset of the page containing only that section and then search it?

Comment: Each question should focus on only one topic - this additional question is just predestined to be [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) -> It's going in the right direction, so describe the behavior in a focused way and also add an expected output to the new question.  We will notice it and support you in finding a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70673963/create-subset-of-soup-for-search-using-beautiful-soup  I reposted the question, seems to be downvoted. I fI can improve the question please let me know Thanks